# C# delegate method with return value

Tags: c#, multithreading, delegates, return

I am making a C# program which is runnning 2 threads. The main UI thread, and a seperate network thread i make myself.

I have figured out, that if i need to change something in the UI from the network thread, i will need to call a deligate method, which works just fine:

```
// Declared as a global variable
public delegate void ListBoxFirst();

//Then call this from the network thread
listBox1.BeginInvoke(new ListBoxFirst(InitListBox));

//Which points to this
public void InitListBox() {
     listBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
}
```

Now i need to be able to read a UI value (a listbox.selectedindex) from the network thread, but it shows the error "cannot implicitly convert type 'system.iasyncresult' to 'int'" if i try it the same way (of course with "int" instead of "void", and a "int a = " before the listbox1.begininvoke). I have googled a lot but im pretty new to C# so i get really lost.

Any help would be much appriciated

Comment: That's running asynchronously.  You can't return read any return value, because it's not done yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out:

```
public int ReadListBoxIndex()
    {
        int count = 0;
        listBox1.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
        {
            count = listBox1.SelectedIndex;
        }));
        return count;
    }
```

Called with a regular

```
int count = ReadListBoxIndex();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `EndInvoke()` to get the result.

Some code:

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            listBox1.Items.AddRange(new[] { "AS","Ram"});           
        }

        protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
        {
            listBox1.BeginInvoke(new Action(GetResult));
        }

        private void GetResult()
        {
            if (InvokeRequired)
            {
                Invoke(new Action(GetResult));
            }
            listBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Well, i think you misunderstood my question. I did figure out how to set the index to 0. What i need, is to READ the value, not set it.

Answer (score 0):

This works also, where `tn` is the treenode you want added to cross thread and `tnret` is the treenode that is returned.

`_treeView.Invoke(new Action(() => tnret = tn.Nodes.Add( name, name )));`